# How to join together data by ID and calculate average value, sql

Tags: sql, database, join

I want to join together two tables and receive result as below. Plus i want to receive AVG value of activity based on User ID.
I was trying this:

```
SELECT Users.ID, (SELECT AVG(Activity) FROM Activity) AS AVG_Activity, Users.Date_started
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Activity
ON Users.ID=Activity.ID
ORDER BY `ID`;
```

But this give me result where i have ID rows as in Activity table (User with ID 1, 2,3 are shown more than once), AVG_activity row shows all user activity average value not grouped on ID's and Date started is OK as based on User ID's.

Users table:

```
ID   Date_started
1    2016-08-03
2    2016-09-12
3    2016-09-13
```

Activity table:

```
ID   Activity   Activity_Date
1       0.5      2016-09-01
2       0.5      2016-10-01
3       0.7      2016-10-01
1       0.1      2016-10-01
1       0.2      2016-11-01
2       0.5      2016-11-01
3       0.8      2016-11-01
```

Result that i want:

```
ID   AVG_Activity   Date_started
1         0.26       2016-08-03
2         0.5        2016-09-12
3         0.75       2016-09-13
```

Comment: Shouldn't the average for `ID = 1` be `0.8/3`?

Comment: Oups, Fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT U.ID, 
       AVG(A.Activity) AVG_Activity,
       U.Date_started
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN Activity A
ON U.ID = A.ID
GROUP BY U.ID, U.Date_started;
```